# Azura's Star doesn't work

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I chose to get Azura's Star instead of the Black Star, and have been trying to use Soul Trap on wolves, deer, etc., but just nothing works.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Arqade SE! Could you edit your question with a little more information about how you're trying the soul trap? Are you using the soul trap spell? Or a soul trap enchanted weapon? Is the soul trap effect taking? Can other gems capture the soul?

Comment: There is a known [bug](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Azura%27s_Star_(Skyrim)#Bugs) that prevents Azura's Star from capturing souls, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which device you are using, you may be able to correct this bug. If you are using an xbox 360, you may be able to fix the bug by clearing your system cache, reinstalling the game, or deleting the "Title Update" file. If you are using pc, the glitch may not be solvable for now.

[Source](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Azura%27s_Star_(Skyrim))